# Is there any way to skip particular words /sign from translation in 'GoogleTranslate()' function in spreadsheets?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-translate

I am using `GoogleTranslate()` with Sheets to translate some contents into different languages. In those contents, we have some hooks `[ ]` that do not need to translate. Example :

```
[username] looked at your profile !
```

I **do not need to translate** hooks like `[username]`.
I'm looking for :

```
[username] a regardé ton profil ! (in french for example)
```

**How can I skip those words from the translation process?**

Comment: Do more substrings between brackets occur in a single value? For example `"[username] looked at your profile over at [linked-in] today!"`

Comment: yeah ! But sometimes i don't have

Comment: A regex for it would be great @JvdV. It is a [request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66637926/is-there-any-way-to-skip-particular-words-sign-from-translation-in-googletrans/66638352?noredirect=1#comment117841205_66638352) by the OP as well

Comment: @marikamitsos, your solution is working for OP since he accepted the answer right? Either way I have added an attempt of solving this too now.

Comment: @JvdV  Actually he accepted your answer that I imagine perfectly meets his needs. :) I didn't have the time to test it. Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My attempt:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=CONCATENATE(INDEX(IF(LEFT(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"\[.*?\]","|$0|"),"|"))="[",SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"\[.*?\]","|$0|"),"|"),SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(GOOGLETRANSLATE(A1,"en","fr"),"\[.*?\]","|$0|"),"|"))))
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** *(following the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66637926/is-there-any-way-to-skip-particular-words-sign-from-translation-in-googletrans#comment117802858_66638352))*

You need to wrap the formula in the [`IFERROR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304) function

```
=IFERROR(REGEXREPLACE(GOOGLETRANSLATE(K2,"en","es"),"\[.*\]",REGEXEXTRACT(K2,"\[.*\]")),
             GOOGLETRANSLATE(K2,"en","es"))
```

---

Original answer

Please try the following

```
=REGEXREPLACE(GOOGLETRANSLATE(K2,"en","es"),"\[.*\]",REGEXEXTRACT(K2,"\[.*\]"))
```

[image]

***(do adjust formula according to your locale)***

Functions used:

- [`REGEXREPLACE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)
- [`GOOGLETRANSLATE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093331)
- [`REGEXEXTRACT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245)

Comment: That's good thank you. however when there is no hook ([]), it does not translate, would there be a way to do if there is a hook then you do not replace, otherwise, you simply translate?

Comment: Wow great thank you ! You seem to be really efficient so I'm going to ask you one more thing, because I'm struggling to find the solution... Sometimes I have few brackets in the middle of a sentence, with your technique it doesn't translate anything anymore. Would you know how to do it?