# Skip translating words with %% and [] in Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I am using GoogleTranslate() with Sheets to translate some contents into different languages. In those contents, we have multiple hooks [ ] and % % in one string that do not need to translate. Example :

`[name] [surname] looked at your profile %number% !`

I do not need to translate hooks like [username] and %number%.

I'm looking for :

`[name] [surname] a regardé ton profil %number% !` (in french for example)

A solution is already provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66637926/is-there-any-way-to-skip-particular-words-sign-from-translation-in-googletrans) for one character using REGEXREPLACE and REGEXEXTRACT. But I need either symbol [xxx] and %xxx% in one formula. Thank you.

Comment: Did you try `"\[.*?\]|%[^%]*%"`?

Comment: Hi. It doesn't seem to work for multiple hooks : 

[name] [surname] looked at your profile %number% ! become [name] [name] a regardé ton profil [name]!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, instead of using the [GOOGLETRANSLATE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093331) with multiple nested functions, you can try [creating a bound script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound#creating_a_bound_script) on your spreadsheet file & then copy/paste the simple ***custom script*** below that contains `translate()` function for a more simplified use of function on your sheet:

***CUSTOM SCRIPT***

```
function translate(range) {
  var container = [];
  //KEEP ALL %***% and [***] INTO A CONTAINER
  var regex = /(\[.*?])|(\%.*?%)/gm,
        stringTest = range,
        matched;
  while(matched = regex.exec(stringTest)){
        container.push(matched[0]);
  }
  //TRANSLATE TEXT TO FRENCH FROM ENGLISH W/O %***% and [***]
  var replacedData = stringTest.replace(regex,'#');
  var toTranslate = LanguageApp.translate(replacedData, 'en', 'fr'); 
  var res = "";
  //REARRANGE THE TRANSLATED TEXT WITH %***% and [***] FROM CONTAINER
  for(x=0;x<toTranslate.split("#").length;x++){
    res = res + toTranslate.split("#")[x]+" "+container[x];
  }
  //RETURN FINAL TRANSLATED TEXT WITH UNMODIFIED %***% and [***] 
  return res.trim().replace("undefined","");
}
```

**SAMPLE RESULT**

[image]

> After saving the script, just simply put `=translate(A1)` *(e.g. the text you want to translate is on cell `A1`)* on a sheet cell and the script will skip any multiple words inside `[***]` & `%***%`, then it will only translate the rest of the text to french.

Comment: This solution works perfectly. However i run into Google App Script limitation as it refreshes everytime. I have around 7000+ strings.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`=arrayformula(if(A1<>"",join("",if(isnumber(flatten(split(GOOGLETRANSLATE(join(" ",iferror(regexreplace(to_text(flatten(split(A1," "))),"(\[.*\])|(\%.*\%)","["&row(A$1:A)&"]"),)),"en","fr"),"[]"))),vlookup(flatten(split(GOOGLETRANSLATE(join(" ",iferror(regexreplace(to_text(flatten(split(A1," "))),"(\[.*\])|(\%.*\%)","["&row(A$1:A)&"]"),)),"en","fr"),"[]")),{sequence(len(regexreplace(A1,"[^\ ]",))+1,1),flatten(split(A1," "))},2,false),flatten(split(GOOGLETRANSLATE(join(" ",iferror(regexreplace(to_text(flatten(split(A1," "))),"(\[.*\])|(\%.*\%)","["&row(A$1:A)&"]"),)),"en","fr"),"[]")))),))`

`GOOGLETRANSLATE` does not work with `ARRAYFORMULA`, but you can drag down this formula from cell `B1` if you want to apply it to multiple rows in column A.

[image]

**Individual steps taken:**

1. Split text by space character, then flatten into one column.

   Cell D1: `=flatten(split(A1," "))`
2. Replace `[***]` and `%***%` with `[row#]`.

   Cell E1: `=arrayformula(iferror(regexreplace(to_text(flatten(split(A1," "))),"(\[.*\])|(\%.*\%)","["&row(A$1:A)&"]"),))`
3. Join the rows into one cell.

   Cell F1: `=join(" ",E:E)`
4. Apply Google Translate.

   Cell G1: `=GOOGLETRANSLATE(F1,"en","fr")`
5. Split by `[]`.

   Cell H1: `=flatten(split(G1,"[]"))`
6. Where rows contain numbers, lookup item 1) above.

   Cell I1: `=arrayformula(if(isnumber(H1:H),vlookup(H1:H,{row(A$1:A),D:D},2,false),H1:H))`
7. Join the rows into one cell.

   Cell J1: `=join(" ",I:I)`

Comment: Thank you. In fact i need several %***% and [***] to work in a sentence...

Comment: Updated solution.